# How to incorporate user input in an input-mode Lua keymap in Neovim?

Tags: input, lua, neovim

In Vim, an input mode map can use `<c-r>=input()` to fetch user input and insert it at the cursor. How is this done in Neovim?

Specific Vimscript example:

```
imap <buffer> <unique> ;_ <c-r>="_{".input("sub:")."}"<cr>
```

What is the Neovim+Lua equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vim.fn.input()` to get the input and store it in a Lua variable. Then get the current cursor position in the current buffer with `vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)`. Finally, set the text in the current buffer at the current cursor position using `vim.api.nvim_buf_set_text()`.

Here is a complete mapping:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("i", "<C-r>", function()
    local user_input = vim.fn.input("Enter input: ")
    local row, col = unpack(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0))
    vim.api.nvim_buf_set_text(0, row - 1, col, row - 1, col, { "_{" .. user_input .. "}" })
end)
```

There's also the option to use `vim.api.nvim_feedkeys()` to insert the text into the buffer.